# Find the "shortcut" names list of executable scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am searching for hours with different key words without success.

The context: I give a name to some scripts `.sh` in order to make them executable anywhere.

For instance, the script `gogo.sh` is in `/etc/gogo_program` directory. In order to execute `gogo.sh` anywhere without having to `cd` to `/ect/gogo_program`, I gave it a name, a kind of "shortcut" called `Cparti`. So, launching a terminal anywhere I just need to type `Cparti` to execute it.

The problem is I don't find the command that lists all these terminal "shortcuts". I did it months ago, now I forgot and even searching with keywords like "alias" and so on, it does not give me the list of "shortcuts". And I need it because I have to check which are present, and have to clean it.

Thanks.

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: If you created your "shortcuts" with `ln -s`, `find` has `-type l`, read `man find`.

Comment: @waltinator Honnestly, I think I used `ln -s` to create symbolic link, but unfortunately `ls -l` or `ls -L` don't give me the name of the symbolic link I gave. Besides as I said in my post, I know the exact name of them like `Cparti`. I don't find a way to go to the source of `Cparti`, in order to give me the list of symbolic links.

Comment: @waltinator I typed `find . -name 'gogo*'  -print` from the root `/`. Then it helped me to see I simply have put my symbolic links in `/usr/bin` where `ls -l` shows it all. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how:

```
find $(echo $PATH | tr ':' ' ') -type l -ls
```